# MySQL DISTINCT one column select all

Tags: mysql

I've been checking stackoverflow and found some similar questions but non is 100% confirmed I think.

I'm trying to select * records from MySQL db either * or firstname, lastname ... + kind of DISTINCT email.

I have some duplicated users in the database but I want to select them only once. Apart of distinct email I also need all other fields.

I've SEEN something like SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS.
Is this accurate? I've received different amount of rows if I only distinct email, different if DISTINCT EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, different when DISTINCT EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME ect.

I suppose result should be the same for DISTINCT(EMAIL) as for DISTINCT EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,... if that's correct query.

Do you have any other ways of selecting those rows in MySQL?

Comment: FirstName, LastName combination may have duplicates...For example `George Bush`

Comment: Please post a sample of your data and what output you are hoping to get. I don't think you have a solid understanding of how distinct works. `DISTINCT` pulls all information but omits duplicate rows. So, if someone is in your DB with the same firstname, lastname and email, and they show three times in the DB, `DISTINCT` will collapse the duplicates into one row and only pull the single distinct (get it?) row.

Comment: Yeah, I know how DISTINCT works for single column but not sure for multi columns. What I was trying to select is distinct of all EMAILS (cos that's unique filed) + other fields selected in the same query. So, if there's 2 users  with the same FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME they should only be distinct by EMAIL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct; you should use `DISTINCT` operator to get the unique data but uniqueness depends on combination.

`DISTINCT EMAIL` will get all the unique EMAIL but

`DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME` will get you the distinct combination of `FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME`. Like `Adam Miller` and `Miller Adam` may not be duplicate.

Similarly, `DISTINCT EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME` will get you the combination of `EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME`. Hence you are observing different result counts.

Comment: Ok, cool. What I'm trying to achieve is SELECT  all data from the table with only 1 unique email. Is this query going to return all distinct EMAIL + other data or is going to distinct other columns like firstname, lastname. I have few duplicate rows in the database but I don't want to missed other compbinations like different emails but the same name, lastname

Comment: NO, you will get combination of columns data which may results in email getting duplicated. Would suggest you to post another question with your table schema, sample data and desired output. You may want to link this question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

well GROUP BY can solve your problem. Here is the sample code.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS GROUP BY `EMAIL`
```

This will group all the duplicate entries of emails.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Technically, the values for all columns except for `email` will come from indeterminate matching rows -- and they might be from different rows.  In *practice* this tends to work, but I would be wary about using something that the documentation explicitly warns against (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).